# Why is this Script only firering in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

why is this .on("click") Event only working on Firefox but not on IE / Chrome / Safari ? The Content .superbox-img is generated dynamically.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#4').on("click", ".superbox-img", function(){  
            var x = $(this).attr('data-med');

             document.getElementById("5").style='display:inline-block;width:100%;';
            document.getElementById("KampagenenImg").src=x;

        });
    });
```

Comment: in html 4 id's cant start with numbers

Comment: To add on what @Dagon see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: also your mix of jquery with raw js is a little odd

Comment: my thoughts exactly. Two things to correct. First do not start id with numbers to stay on safe side and secondly use $() selectors for all your actions.

Comment: `use $() selectors for all your actions` - or don't use $() at all - is also a valid lifestyle choice

Comment: Thanks Guys ! Problem is solved !